# Does anyone have any experience using Swiper.js in Angular Unversal with SSR?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, swiper.js

I am trying to implement a swiper. I have an app using Angular Universal. When I initially load my app, the swiper initializes, but there is one bug where it lets me swipe way too far left and right. It doesn't just snap back if i try to swipe too far.

When I navigate away from the page with the swiper and then back, the swiper works as expected. I am assuming this has something to do with the server-side rendering. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

this is my config:

```
var sortFilterSwiper = new Swiper("#sortSwiperMobile", {
spaceBetween: 0,
slidesPerView: 'auto',
centeredSlides: false

});
```

Like I said, it appears to work well in the browser app, but I am having trouble getting it to work on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Same in my project but I've fixed like this:

```
import { EventReplayer } from 'preboot';


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  this.swipeConfig = {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    initialSlide: 0,
    updateOnWindowResize: true,
    preloadImages: false
  };
  this.eventReplayer.replayAll();
  this.cd.markForCheck();
}
```

}

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Awesome! This is great. I had a different more hacky solution, so I appreciate this.

Comment: share it with me :)

Comment: I added a touchstart event that configured swiper on touch. It worked most of the time but was pretty sketchy.

Comment: And how it looks like, before touchstart? In my project are responsive issues also.

Comment: Here is a general idea of what my code looked like (HTML) `<div  (click)="init = true" (touchstart)="init = true" (touchend)="init = true"><swiper [config]="config"
        [initialize]="init">...</swiper></div>`. TS: `config: SwiperOptions = {
    spaceBetween: 0,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: false,
    direction: 'horizontal'
  };`

Comment: have u tried eventReplayer ? I think, it is much better sollution for u too.

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using swiper with Angular Universal Server Side Rendering, I installed `ngx-swiper-wrapper` package and it worked fine without any error

reference package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper`

Comment: package deprecated